# Compress Or Reduce the size of sqlite database file in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sqlite

i want to **reduce the size of sqlite database file**. and i had also use **VACUUM** command but still the size of database file is same. can any one help me for this problem?
Thank you

Comment: where is this database stored?

Comment: What I mean is it in the app store delivered with the app, or is it in the Documents folder being actively used?

Comment: it is in document folder.